# Docker logs/information gathering on Windows 10

Tags: docker, docker-desktop, docker-logs

I have a challenge to collect logs/information on Windows docker desktop. It should be not only container logs/information, it'd be logs/information of docker as a whole. 
For example: I want to have a container list, a list of containers ports or changes of files in container filesystem.  
 **How to implement it?** 
 I know it is implemented by osquery on Linux and MacOs, but not sure on Windows.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.